# Are there HTML5 desktop app frameworks (like Titanium or Adobe AIR) that run on V8 or Rhino instead of JavaScriptCore?

Tags: html, titanium, rhino, v8, javascriptcore

Our product, a desktop app, is composed of a ton of HTML5 and JavaScript together with a thin platform-specific layer that is basically a WebKit shell. Since this is much the same strategy as a framework like [Appcelerator Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/products/titanium-desktop-application-development/), and we waste way too much effort on this custom WebKit shell code, we were hoping to switch to Titanium or a similar framework to handle that for us.

However, such a switch would be much more compelling if we could pick up a nice modern JavaScript engine in the process. Like Titanium, we're currently on JavaScriptCore, which sucks (they still don't have [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=26382)!). We'd take either V8, for speed and modernity, or Rhino, for [yummy JavaScript 1.7/ECMAScript Harmony](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.7) features.

Does anyone know of a framework for building desktop apps with HTML5 that uses either of these engines? Or some way of making either work with Titanium that will be very little effort? I saw the [v8_titanium](https://github.com/appcelerator/v8_titanium) and [rhino_titanium](https://github.com/appcelerator/rhino_titanium) projects on GitHub, but see no mention of them anywhere else, or any documentation on how to use them. And the [Adobe AIR WebKit page](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/webkit/Webkit) has nothing encouraging either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ended up on [Chromium Embedded](http://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/), which is a bit rough around the edges but definitely gets the job done.

Answer (score 3):

Node-webkit is just about done being ported to use cef3. https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/tree/cef

Comment: +1, I've been looking forward to this. Hope it works out well.

Comment: After using appjs, I ended up switching to Node WebKit as it seemed better supported (it's an Intel project).  Also, the packaging options are great with the ability to create a one file executable.

Comment: AppJs actually has a poor canvas performance. Node-webkit is fast and is quite suitable for packaging HTML5/CSS/JS games.

Answer (score 2):

To follow up on this, we've just published binaries for all 3 platforms at https://github.com/milani/appjs | http://appjs.org. That's Chromium and Node, provided as a package that works out of the box with no configuration cross platform.

Comment: This is really exciting. Looking forward to watching it evolve.

Comment: How is appjs distinct from node-webkit? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8794140/is-it-possible-to-create-desktop-applications-with-node-js

Comment: one difference is that appjs is a module for node whereas node-webkit compiles node into webkit

Comment: Is it possible to develop Google Chrome extensions using node-webkit, by any chance? It looks like it would be a great tool for developing browser extensions (if it were possible).

Comment: Looks like a dead project now.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could count Mozilla XULRunner as "app framework". It's more like embedded Firefox than framework, though.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/xulrunner

It's much much more complex and powerful than Adobe AIR or Titanium.

Comment: You sure can. We created and open-sourced [Webapp XUL Wrapper](https://github.com/neam/webapp-xul-wrapper) a while ago, and it works great for publishing HTML5 applications as desktop apps. It is "a XUL-based wrapper and build scripts for packaging a webapp into distributable bundles for Mac, Windows, and Linux."

Answer (score 1):

You can use Adobe AIR to build HTML5 desktop apps.

AIR uses the webkit engine:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/devappsflex/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7ec1.html

See also:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/devappshtml/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7ecc.html